# How to start new row to skipping some columns in html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow, tablecolumn

I want to skip some coulmns in table ?
This is my table[image]

I want the last row start from below the cost like in the below picture. [image]

Anyone Please Help me? Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

as per your question you need table like below, please comment if any query.

```css
    .hidetd
    {
        visibility: hidden;
         
    }
    .withborder
    {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
     <td class="withborder">Assmbl</td>
     <td class="hidetd"></td>
     <td class="hidetd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder">name</td>
        <td class="withborder">cost per </td>
        <td class="withborder">unit</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder">pc rnd</td>
        <td class="withborder">Cost</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder">pc rnd</td>
        <td class="withborder">Cost</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder">  </td>
        <td class="withborder">pc rnd</td>
        <td class="withborder">Cost</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder">  </td>
        <td class="withborder">pc rnd</td>
        <td class="withborder">Cost</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder">  </td>
        <td class="withborder">pc rnd</td>
        <td class="withborder">Cost</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="hidetd"></td>
        <td class="hidetd"></td>
        <td class="hidetd"></td>
        <td class="withborder">Total</td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
        <td class="withborder"></td>
    </tr> 
 </table>
```